# apt-get update - could not resolve 'w<WG4tj^fn1'

Tags: updates

I need some help, I have a honeypot installed in my company and currently, I can not run the command apt-get update, because it shows the following message:

```
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
    Could not resolve 'w<WG4tj^fn1'
```

This error appeared after they put my credential in the password vault system. I can't update the honeypot.

Comment: The version of Ubuntu needs to be added to the question. Please use edit and not in comments.

Comment: You probably put your proxy config wrong, because that sounds like your password not the hostname necessary for resolution.  By the way, have IT reset your password ;)

Comment: Please add your version of Ubuntu.